# Question regardles primes and the fundamental theorem of arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I have been reading through my book of practice proofs and came across this particular question which has stumped me.

> $p$ and $q$ are primes. Prove $\forall p \in \mathbb{Z}, \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}, (p^2\mid q^2) \Rightarrow p=q$.

I assume that the proof starts with stating that $p^n$ and $q^k$ in their product of primes form but I am unsure on how division in these forms work or if I'm even correct in assuming that is the first step. Can anyone give me an explanation of the answer so that even a 16 year old can understand? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't that be "Question regarding ...." ?

Comment: Please do not remove the entire content of your question.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if $p^n|q^k$, then in particular $p|q^k$. Now use the fact that if $p$ is prime and $p|ab$, then $p|a$ or $p|b$.

Comment: That might eventually get you to $p|q$, so you need either one more step or a different approach.

Comment: It's a hint to the first step.... not a full solution. More steps will of course be needed.

Comment: Such a hint might be: You haven't yet used that $q$ is prime.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ By the Rational Root Test, if $\,(p,q)=1\,$ then $\, (q/p)^2 \in\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\,q/p\in \Bbb Z.$